# Windows Intergrated Authentication with reverse proxy issue with Safari

Tags: kerberos, ntlm, spnego

I'm having a application which has Windows Integrated Authentication, for internet users we are having a reverse proxy which has a IIS server which will authenticate using basic authentication then redirected to the actual application, every thing works as expected in IE and firefox but in safari there is a second login dialog box appers.

When I did a packet capture using wireshark I noticed that in IE and FF the basic authetication which is carried forwared to the actual application from IIS server but in Safari there is a NTLM negotion in between because of this my application asks for one more login dialog. Dose any one knows why safari is behaving like this?

Comment: I have deleted my answer, we tried Safari several times and it fails. Seems like Apple had this fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is an issue with basic authentication and HTTP redirection